# T sql - How to store results from a dynamic query using EXEC or EXECUTE sp_executesql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a dynamic query.  Let's say i have a table like below, which represents the hierarchy level of a sales agent:

```
AgentNumber Level1Agent Level2Agent Level3Agent Level4Agent Level5Agent
1122334455  1122334499  1122334488  1122334477  1122334466  1122334455
```

I want to be able to dynamically select a level based on a specified agent.  My EXECUTE statement seems to work correctly, but how do I get the result stored in a variable I can use later?  Every answer I have found seems to only get me a success return variable, not the actual query result.

Below is my code:

```
DECLARE @level INT = 1;
DECLARE @agent CHAR(10) = 1122334455;
DECLARE @colname NVARCHAR(11) = CONCAT('Level',@level,'Agent');
DECLARE @whereclause NVARCHAR(35) = CONCAT('WHERE AgentNumber = ',@agent);

DECLARE @qry NVARCHAR(300) = 'SELECT ' + @colname + ' FROM dbo.TABLE ' + @whereclause;
DECLARE @up NVARCHAR(10);

EXECUTE sp_executesql @qry, @up OUT
SELECT @up
```

The output of @up is NULL.  If I change the last two lines to:

```
EXECUTE @up = sp_executesql @qry
SELECT @up
```

Now the output of @up is 0.

I want the output of 1122334499 and I need it stored in a variable that can later be used and inserted into a table.

Comment: This is pretty scary code. It is vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: The problem is that you are confusing a return value and an output variable. I don't see why you need a parameter here to hold the value of the column. And since you are using a scalar variable this will only hold 1 value so if our query returns multiple rows this isn't going to work at all.

Comment: Can you have more than 1 row returned? Or is this always going to only return a single row?

Comment: If I create a temp table and input the results into a table, it works, but it seems like I should be able to get the result without creating just a table for it.

Comment: There will only always be on result/row returned because you are specifying the level to a specific agent.

Comment: I need to hold the value because it will be used later.

Comment: I just noticed that in a comment below you mentioned you are running this in a loop. Perhaps we can help you get rid of that loop also. I have a feeling we could turn this into an inline table valued function and get rid of the dynamic sql completely. It would be a lot simpler to understand and maintain plus it would be a LOT faster.

Comment: Basically, I need one record per policy per agent of the up line.  For the example I gave above, there would be 5 records.  I'm dealing with hundreds of policies, but there is not always the same number of agents in the up line.  There can be 2 agents or 6 or 9.  It varies.  That's why I'm using a loop and that's why there's the dynamic field name.  I'm not familiar with inline table valued functions so I don't know if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fully functional example of how you can do this. Notice this is using a parameterized where clause and quotename around the column name in the dynamic sql to prevent sql injection.

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Agents') is not null
    drop table #Agents

create table  #Agents 
(
    AgentNumber char(10)
    , Level1Agent char(10)
    , Level2Agent char(10)
    , Level3Agent char(10)
    , Level4Agent char(10)
    , Level5Agent char(10)
)

insert #Agents
select '1122334455', '1122334499', '1122334488', '1122334477', '1122334466', '1122334455'

DECLARE @level INT = 3;
DECLARE @agent CHAR(10) = 1122334455;
DECLARE @colname NVARCHAR(11) = CONCAT('Level',@level,'Agent');

declare @agentout char(10)

DECLARE @qry NVARCHAR(300) = 'SELECT @agent_out = ' + quotename(@colname) + ' FROM #Agents WHERE AgentNumber = @agentin';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @qry, N'@agentin char(10), @agent_out char(10) output', @agentin = @agent, @agent_out = @agentout output

select @agentout
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
DECLARE @level INT = 1;
DECLARE @agent CHAR(10) = 1122334455;
DECLARE @colname NVARCHAR(11) = CONCAT('Level',@level,'Agent');
DECLARE @whereclause NVARCHAR(35) = CONCAT('WHERE AgentNumber = ',@agent);

DECLARE @qry NVARCHAR(300) = 'SELECT @agentout=' + @colname + ' FROM dbo.TABLE ' + @whereclause;
DECLARE @up NVARCHAR(10);

EXECUTE sp_executesql @qry, N'@agentout NVARCHAR(10) OUTPUT', @agentout=@up OUTPUT
SELECT @up
```

Comment: This would be a little better if you used QUOTENAME around the column name and parameterized the where clause. It would be pretty safe from sql injection then.

Comment: I agree with you, but for now we can focus on the main issue he is looking for, which is to store the output to a variable using dynamic query so that he can use that variable further. @ittiekat - Please check the query.

Comment: Protecting against sql injection should ALWAYS be part of a solution.

Comment: This did not work for me.  No output came from the "select @up" statement.

Comment: @ittiekat - Are you sure you have data in your table? I am saying because it works in my DB just with different table!

Comment: You had this solution before the solution you accepted, this is disappointing. Anyway I am happy that your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable table and makes your query insert the results you want there. Something like this:

```
declare @results table(field1 varchar(max), field2 varchar(max));
declare @sqlStatement varchar(max);

set @sqlStatement = 'insert into @results(field1, field2) select field1, field2 from table';


EXECUTE @sqlStatement;

select * from @results; --It will print the results from your sql statement!
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried this and it does work.  It just seems like there should be a way without creating a table.  My code is in a loop so will be run several hundred times.  I'll have to keep dropping the table.

Comment: You doesn't need to keep dropping the table. Just delete the content of the table at the end of the looping and reuse the same table at the beginning of the next loop.